# Orthodox Easter calculator

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have code for calculating the date for orthodox Easter and it makes me cry when I look at the `if`-`else` part. Please give your suggestions on how to make it shine (if possible).

I guess I can format day/month to DateTime format but I'm afraid it'll bring just more mess.

It works just fine though [this](http://repl.it/2d5/2).

[Source](https://github.com/a-for-alegria/EaterCalculator)

```
puts "- Hello, I'm EasterEvaluator. I can tell you when will be(or was) Easter."
puts "- Please enter the year which you'r interested in:"
year = gets.chomp.to_i
a = year % 19
b = year % 4
c = year % 7
d = (19*a+15) % 30
e = (2*b + 4*c + 6*d + 6) % 7
f = d + e
if f<=9 
    easter = 22+f
    easter = easter + 13 if year > 1918
    if easter > 31
        easter = easter - 31
        month = "April"
    else
        month = "March"
    end
else
    easter = f-9
    easter = easter + 13 if year > 1918
    if easter > 30
        easter = easter-30 
        month = "May"
    else 
        month = "April"
    end
end

puts "- In #{year}, Easter is going to be on #{easter} of #{month}."
```

Comment: This appears to be an implementation of the [Meeus Julian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Meeus_Julian_algorithm).

Comment: Have you seen the gem holidays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested psuedo-code, but the key is to realize f = number of days from March 22 to Orthodox Easter.

```
(* f gives Easter as the number of days since March 22 *) 

easter = f+22+(year<1918)*13 

month = "March"; # default 
if f > 31 {month="April"; day=f-31} 
if f > 61 {month="May"; day=f-61}
```

You might also post to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com